# Save rpart decision tree rules to a dataframe

Tags: r, rpart, rattle

I am using rattle::asRules() to display rpart decision rules to the screen,
my goal is to save the rules to a tidy data frame.

Here is an example:

```
library(rpart)
library(rattle)

fit <- rpart(Kyphosis ~ Age + Number + Start, data = kyphosis)
rattle::asRules(fit, TRUE)
```

Desired Output:
[image]

Comment: Printing of the table is implemented [using `cat`](https://github.com/cran/rattle/blob/master/R/asRules.rpart.R). Your best bet would be to fork repo and modify the function. At the least output raw values (currently the result is order of values).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I used the sink() function to diverts R output to a file.

```
sink("rules.txt")
rattle::asRules(fit, TRUE)
sink()
```

Comment: Having the same issue. This is the only thing I can find that works. But I made a couple alterations to avoid saving to an external file.
`sink("clipboard")
rattle::asRules(tree, compact = TRUE)
treerules <- read.table(file = "clipboard", sep = "\t", header = F, stringsAsFactors = F)
sink()`